# Как вставить в одну ячейку excel текст с табуляцией

Tags: excel

Импортирую данные из sql в excel. В ячейке sql содержится текст с табуляцей.

При импорте данных в excel данные вставляются не в одну ячейку, а распределяются на несколько. Подскажите, как настроить формат ячеек в excel, чтобы данные вставлялись в одну ячейку вне зависимости от количества переносов строк и количества текста в исходной ячейке.

Comment: *Импортирую данные из sql в excel.* Как именно?

Comment: Просто выделяю ячейки из sql server и вставляю в лист excel. Ячейки, где цифры или небольшое количество символов вставляются корректно, а где табуляция - нет. Знаю, что вроде бы есть способ решения на стороне excel.

Comment: Сомневаюсь... такой способ вставки - совершенно неуправляемый. При копипасте значения полей разделяются именно табуляциями - и нет способа отличить табуляцию между полями от табуляции в значении поля.

Answer (score 0):

Может для кого-нибудь будет полезным. Решение на стороне sql server. В запросе обернуть поле в функцию REPLACE, заменив перенос на символ пробела.
REPLACE(Ваше поле, CHAR(10), ' ')

Comment: Лучше заменить на символ, который не встречается в данных. После вставки этот символ заменить на символ переноса строки (одно действие для всего диапазона)